# The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

found solutions on this site but nothing is working for me

I am learning references to other projects and builds and have this error while trying to call method .
p.s. creating an object with reference to that build is working fine , only calling the method  generates this exception  .
maybe this will help to explain the problem

core 6 target framework 4.8
[image]

[image]

I did this , created a new project enter image description here

using "Windows Forms App" template instead of regular "Console App" . everything is working fine now :
enter image description here

, BUT in book it says to create a Console App . If there is no mistake in the book (really need Console App template) . I would be glad to know how to figure out this exception . Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Try following these steps on a fresh solution/project, and see if it works fine. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a66wsCRSgDk  If it's fine, then you can compare your project with this new project and see what's different. If steps from the video doesn't give you a working project, then it's probably something wrong with the VisualStudio or build tools.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed it's Core6 and VS2022, I have actually not used those yet, they are quite new, there's still a very slight possibility of a bug there, or  small chance that something has changed and that the video is already obsolete. In any case, it's hard to say anything more with this lack of details you provided.

Comment: What is "core 6"? Do you mean "net6.0"?

Comment: He's using net4.8, what are you talking about @quetzalcoatl?

Comment: Class Library is net 4.8 / but the project runs on net 6 / maybe this is the problem ?

Comment: Klaus Gütter
 yes net 6

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did this :
created a Console App (.NET Framework (max 4.8 available)  )  like in Class Library (targeted framework 4.8) .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYqb9.jpg)
after adding a reference to this library it compiles just fine

Comment: Regarding your deleted post with "in book it says to create a Console App . If there is no mistake in the book (really need Console App template)" - for creating Windows Forms apps, the best initial template is - "Windows Forms App (C#)", just like you tried before when it worked fine. The book you are using is either outdated, or misleading, or ... it was correct some time ago and maybe it had some smart idea (like having both the console Forms UI at the same time, etc), and that smart idea might have led to problems when C# and VS have evolved a bit and now the book isn't 100% right